# Intuition and reasoning behind conversion factor calculation for bond futures

Tags: bond, bond-yields, bond-futures

I am currently reading the chapter on bond futures from J.C. Hull. The author states the procedure for calculating [conversion factor](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cheapesttodeliver.asp) as

> The conversion factor for a bond is set equal to the quoted price the bond would have
>   per dollar of principal on the first day of the delivery month on the assumption that the
>   interest rate for all maturities equals 6% per annum (with semiannual compounding).
>   The bond maturity and the times to the coupon payment dates are rounded down to the
>   nearest 3 months for the purposes of the calculation. The practice enables the exchange
>   to produce comprehensive tables. If, after rounding, the bond lasts for an exact number of 6-month periods, the first coupon is assumed to be paid in 6 months. If, after
>   rounding, the bond does not last for an exact number of 6-month periods (i.e., there
>   are an extra 3 months), the first coupon is assumed to be paid after 3 months and
>   accrued interest is subtracted.

I have $3$ related questions regarding this procedure:

1. Why is this procedure of rounding off to three months done ? What is the logic behind it ? If I am not wrong looking at the time left to maturity of bond at start of delivery month is say $2$ years and $4$ months. I know the coupon the first coupon payment will happen next two months ( I assume coupons are given every $6$ months and are regular).
2. `first coupon is assumed to be paid after 3 months and accrued interest is subtracted`. 
   Why is the accrued interest subtracted from the discounted value calculated, to get the quoted current price ? I have attached the example where the coupon cash payments are discounted and then accrued interest is subtracted. 
   [image]
   If I am not wrong the price calculated in example $2$ by discounting is the quoted price only ?
3. Why is the constant discounting rate of $6$ per cent used ? Why isn't the yields from the zero yield curve used. Wouldn't that also the eliminate the cheapest to deliver and bring all bonds in the nasket to more equal footing ? Does this have anything to do with point $1$.

PS: I googled around but could not get answer to my questions. I found this question related [Conversion factor for bonds](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/conversion-factor-for-bonds), but could not understand much.

PPS: I am really sorry for my naive question. I am a complete beginner and am having hard time with this section of the book. And am stuck on it. I am just looking for some intuitive explanation if a concrete one is complex.

Comment: Believe it or not at the time some committee of the CBOT designed these complicated and somewhat arbitrary rules, 6% was thought to be a "typical" interest rate.

Comment: @AlexC sir, i will highly appreciate it if you could add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't calculated a conversion factor in a long time but it would appear that the answer is given in the quotation "to allow the exchange to produce a table of values". If you perform this ad hoc rounding in steps 1 and 2 then you reduce any arbitrary bond to an instrument that be determined from a table.

With regards to the 6% that is the de facto futures contract specification and has been for many years. When you pay $x$ for a bond future you are willing and expecting to accept delivery of a 6% bond for the maturity as also specified on the contract. The secondary artifact that only certain bonds exist that may or may not have a 6% coupon and precisely the right maturity means there is a need to convert your expected futures price to one that is fair for both parties to settle on another bond of different specification.

In the end a simpler and more transparent conversion of settlement prices benefits the exchange and traders since one can perform analytics with knowledge of cash values and expected returns.